# Google maps infowindow off center

Tags: jquery, google-maps

if you go to the following website:

http://showsec.rnmtest2.co.uk/contact-us

You will see there is a map on the left and then the option to select an office on the right. If you click one of these offices it triggers an infowindow to popup on the map, however the infowindow is not centered and is overflows out of the right side of the map meaning that the close button isn't visible without dragging the map. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your map is fairly narrow and the infowindow is simply too wide for it. You can force the infowindow to use a narrower width by specifying its `maxWidth` property when you create it, such as:

```
var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ maxWidth: 300 });
```